# Marionette throw error as "Uncaught NoElError: An "el" must be specified for a region."

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In my app, I have a regions like :

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','marionette'], 
  function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette) {
    "use strict";
    socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

    socialApp.AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        template:'#appTemplate',
        regions: {
            header : '#header',
            content : '#content',
            footer : '#footer'
    },
    initialize:function(){
            console.log('layout intialized');
    }
    });

    return socialApp.AppLayout;
});
```

to append my regions i have the container like this:

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','marionette'], 
  function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette) {
    "use strict";
    socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

    socialApp.AppRegion = Backbone.Marionette.Region({
        el:'#wrapper',
    initialize:function(){
      console.log('from wrapper');
    }
    });

    return socialApp.AppRegion;
});
```

Now I am calling both of the function:

```
socialApp.Layout = new appLayout(); //calling layout
    socialApp.AppContainer = new appContainer; //calling container
    socialApp.AppContainer.show(socialApp.Layout); //i am showing to container
```

But I am getting a error as :

```
Uncaught NoElError: An "el" must be specified for a region.
```

how to fix this? what is the wrong here, any one figure out me please?

**Here is my Controller for additional info**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    './model/loginModel',
    './views/loginView'
    ],function ($,_,Backbone,Marionette,loginModel,loginView) {
    "use strict";
    socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

    socialApp.loginController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        _initialize:function(){
            console.log('initi')
            this.loginView = new loginView({model:new loginModel}).render().el;
            console.log(this.layout.header.show(this.loginView));
        }
    });

    return socialApp.loginController;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m trying to follow and understand your code, but it’s really hard. It would help if you could fix the indentation, and possibly the reorder things and remove all irrelevant boilerplate code.

Anyway, I would suggest you use `Marionette.Application`, to which you can attach regions directly, instead of this container thing you’re creating:

```
var SocialApp = new Marionette.Application;
SocialApp.addRegions({ root: '#wrapper' });
```

Then you would create your `AppLayout` view, and attach that to the App’s root region:

```
SocialApp.root.show(new AppLayout)
```